# Let $U = \{ 1, 2, \dots 2^n\}$ and $S \subset U$, specifically $S = \{x_1, \dots x_n\}$. Define $N = \prod_{i < j}(x_i - x_j)$.

Tags: number-theory

Let $U = \{ 1, 2, \dots 2^n\}$ and $S \subset U$, specifically $S = \{x_1, \dots x_n\}$. Define $N = \prod_{i < j}(x_i - x_j)$.

Then how can we prove that there exist a prime $p$ such that $p \leq \log_2 N$ and $p$ does not divide $N$?

Comment: with $\log$ do you mean binary log?

Comment: @CarryonSmiling yes.

Comment: shouldn't it be $i<j$ instead of $i\neq j$?

Comment: @CarryonSmiling Sorry, yes it should be. Edited.

Comment: I believe some corrections are required, because $U=\{1,2,3,...2^3\}$ and $S=\{1,2,3\} \subset U$, thus $N=(3-2)(3-1)(2-1)=2$, pretty much no such primes here.

Comment: The same applies for $U=\{1,2,3,...2^4\}$ and $S=\{1,2,3,4\} \subset U$, giving $N=(4-3)(4-2)(4-1)(3-2)(3-1)(2-1)=12$ where $2<\log_2{12},3<\log_2{12}$ both dividing $12$.